# Attempting to upgrade Windows 7 Home Premium to Windows 10 and Receving a Black screen at 79%

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10-upgrade

I am running Windows 7 Home Premium on an Acer Aspire All In One Z3771.

The first time I attempted to upgrade to Windows 10 I did it through the automatic window on my computer as my upgrade had finally arrived. It stopped at 79% rebooted and never came back up, no mouse cursor, just a black screen. I rebooted and had no operating system. I did a factory rest and had to dl over 100 updates to get back to where I should be. I backed up everything, made a system image and a boot disc.

I have since attempted to upgrade around 20 times since then and at least now it restores my system. It gets through Copying Files and then moves on to Installing Features and Drivers, once that portion has completed to 100% It puts the overall Installation percentage to 79% reboots and goes to the black screen and stays. I reboot and it attempts to recover installation but always reverts to restoring my previous version of windows.

Things I have already tried: Clean Boot, Disabled all anti-virus, Scan disc, Defrag, used the windows media creation tool to install windows 10, unplugged my router during installation after dl windows 10.

What could be causing this? Are there any alternate ways of upgrading to Windows 10?

Comment: Sometimes it happens becaus there's no engough space in disk. Also check that your Intel NX or XD bit is enabled in your BIOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it is a a driver issue, **Setuperr.log** might provide a clue. It should be exist in **%windir%\panther**

Answer (score 1):

Just want to share my success upgrading Z3771 Windows 7 Home Premium to Windows10, after at least 10 attempts. The Acer site did not list z3771 as supported for Windows 10, but I wasn't going to give up, being a IT professional.

My z3771 was upgraded to 8.1, after a few unsuccessful attempts related to driver conflict errors etc.. I followed some advice on blogs - cleaned up my Kapersky anti-virus, unistall all my apps, changed settings to clean boot, etc.. but keep failing until I reinstall back to original Windows 7 Home Prem, then do a clean boot reconfig. downloaded windows 10 install exe from Microsoft - and hey presto.. , like all my other Windows 10 upgrade for half a dozen PCs.,..I got a nice and clean Windows 10 on the z3771 - all drivers good as gold !!!

Here's the steps:

1. Backup your data files.
2. Do a reinstall of Windows 7 Home Prem.
3. The Windows 7 install will ask for an update, so let that follow through.
4. Next step is critical. Go to Microsoft clean boot page and follow the instructions for Windows 7 clean boot config.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/kb/929135
5. Go to Get Windows 10 on Microsoft site and download the exe file for 64-bit.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/windows-10-upgrade

6. Run the downloaded GWXWebWindows.exe.
7. Follow the instructions and the installation rolls out.. but this time.. no more stalls.. no more roll-back to original system... but a perfect Windows 10 install for z3771. Unbelievable !!